# USB Drive is not working on Lubuntu

Tags: partitioning, usb, lubuntu, usb-drive

I've a 16GB USB 3.0 drive and it's not working on either Lubuntu 18.04 or Windows 10.

What I tried:

- Connecting to other ports.
- Trying EaseUs Partition Master and Partition Wizard on Win 10 but both are not even detecting the device.
- "Disks" program on Lubuntu is not detecting/listing the device.

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep -i USB`:

```
[    0.277389] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.277389] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.277389] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.277389] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    5.314634] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    5.314763] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    5.332045] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    5.332076] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    5.332078] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    5.332079] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    5.332080] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic ehci_hcd
[    5.332080] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    5.332223] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.332455] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    5.352049] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    5.352081] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    5.352082] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    5.352083] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    5.352084] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic ehci_hcd
[    5.352085] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    5.352217] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.352351] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    5.352367] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    5.352488] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    5.353685] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    5.353686] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    5.353687] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    5.353688] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
[    5.353688] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    5.353819] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.356624] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    5.356626] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0  SuperSpeed
[    5.356658] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    5.356659] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    5.356660] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    5.356661] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-70-generic xhci-hcd
[    5.356662] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    5.356791] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.672012] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    5.692009] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    5.700004] usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    5.832316] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8008
[    5.832318] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    5.832473] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.852461] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    5.852463] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    5.852738] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.857393] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002
[    5.857394] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.857395] usb 3-2: Product: USB Keyboard
[    5.857396] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SIGMACHIP
[    5.983966] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    6.198865] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=055e
[    6.198867] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    6.198868] usb 3-6: Product: Lenovo EasyCamera
[    6.198869] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: Generic
[    6.198869] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: REMOVED
[    6.327999] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    6.477219] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3004
[    6.477221] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    6.603997] usb 3-9: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    6.755697] usb 3-9: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=8105
[    6.755699] usb 3-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    6.755700] usb 3-9: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[    6.755701] usb 3-9: Manufacturer: YSPRINGTECH
[    6.767706] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    6.767707] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    6.769520] input: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0001/input/input9
[    6.828224] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[    6.828396] input: SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0002/input/input10
[    6.892249] hid-generic 0003:1C4F:0002.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[    6.892364] input: YSPRINGTECH USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9:1.0/0003:10C4:8105.0003/input/input11
[    6.892615] hid-generic 0003:10C4:8105.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [YSPRINGTECH USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input0
[   25.354775] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   25.747868] input: Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/input/input20
[   25.747921] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   25.747922] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   25.768357] usb 3-7: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   25.768498] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   26.075959] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   26.225084] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3004
[   26.225086] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  184.759319] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  184.779857] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0917
[  184.779862] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  184.779865] usb 4-1: Product: USB 3.0
[  184.779867] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: innostor
[  184.779869] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: REMOVED
[  184.836257] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  184.836431] scsi host5: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[  184.836508] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  184.847222] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  185.874746] usb 4-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[  185.878288] usb 4-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[  186.003288] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

Output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: xx-xx-xx-xx-xx

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     616447     614400   300M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2      616448     821247     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3      821248    1083391     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1083392  127117311  126033920  60.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   127117312 1759834111 1632716800 778.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1759834112 1775835135   16001024   7.6G Linux swap
/dev/sda7  1775835136 1953523711  177688576  84.7G Linux filesystem
```

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  60.1G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 778.6G  0 part /mnt/ebram96
├─sda6   8:6    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda7   8:7    0  84.7G  0 part /
```

So, is it dead or should I try ??

Comment: Can you try the device on another machine? From what you've described, the device sounds dead.

Comment: Check it's SMART data; if it's a cheap device that doesn't have SMART diagnostics, then it's easier to just replace the device as it wasn't intended for long-term use.  If it's a flash-drive, each write can do damage (unlike reads); and you've *blown* some of it's storage capacity in your last write most probably (my 2c anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your disk on a USB 2.0 port, or a completely different machine & os.

`Disable of device-initiated U1 failed` usually indicates there is a device failure, instead of an OS failure and you will have to buy a new drive.

Comment: I already tried it, not working.

Comment: @EbramShehata Then this looks more like a hardware problem. Now you may want to buy a new drive on amazon...sorry to hear that.